# Question about code from webpack documentation site

Tags: javascript, webpack

[From webpack's documentation:](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/)

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: ['style-loader'](/loaders/style-loader) },
          {
            loader: ['css-loader'](/loaders/css-loader),
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          },
          { loader: ['sass-loader'](/loaders/sass-loader) }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

What does the following line do?

```
          { loader: ['style-loader'](/loaders/style-loader) },
```

I pasted it into the console and it's giving me errors and I am not familiar with this kind of syntax in js. AFAIK, webpack configuration should be valid js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the following syntax instead:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: ['style-loader'] },
          {
            loader: ['css-loader'],
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          },
          { loader: ['sass-loader'] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I have submitted a PR [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/pull/2831) to get it fixed in the docs as well.